# How do I strtotime in python?

Tags: python, datetime

I'm scraping a a page that includes among other things, date information. So I have a variable named `warrant_issued` that contains `u'11/5/2003'` -- I want to store this as a machine readable date. PHP has a handy `strtotime` function that works fabulously. I was hoping that [datetime](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)'s [strptime](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) would help me but it doesn't seem to be available in my version of `datetime` -- here is everything in my tab complete on `datetime.`

```
In [231]: datetime.
datetime.MAXYEAR           datetime.__hash__          datetime.__sizeof__
datetime.MINYEAR           datetime.__init__          datetime.__str__
datetime.__class__         datetime.__name__          datetime.__subclasshook__
datetime.__delattr__       datetime.__new__           datetime.date
datetime.__dict__          datetime.__package__       datetime.datetime
datetime.__doc__           datetime.__reduce__        datetime.datetime_CAPI
datetime.__file__          datetime.__reduce_ex__     datetime.time
datetime.__format__        datetime.__repr__          datetime.timedelta
datetime.__getattribute__  datetime.__setattr__       datetime.tzinfo
```

I'm using iPython 2.7.2+

Am I barking up the wrong tree here? What's the best way to turn `u'11/5/2003'` into a date?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`strptime()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) is definitely the right approach, it's just a class method for the [`datetime` class](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) (confusingly part of the `datetime` module).

That is, `datetime.datetime.strptime()` is what you're looking for (and not `datetime.strptime()`.

Comment: But the php strtotime function can automatically detect the string format, is there any similar approaches in python?

Comment: The [`dateutil` library](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) can parse datetime strings (inferring their format). However, note that "11/5/2003" is not an unambiguous format (MM/DD or DD/MM differs by locale), so dateutil should be used with caution in this case.

Comment: @DavidCain php warns about these issues as well. I personally like the seemingly magic ability to parse date strings using `strtotime()` in php  into the correct format but dislike the lack of specificity.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to the comment reply from @David Cain:

> The dateutil library can parse datetime strings (inferring their format). However, note that "11/5/2003" is not an unambiguous format (MM/DD or DD/MM differs by locale), so dateutil should be used with caution in this case. – David Cain

So an alternative good practice is to use the dateutil library:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> dt = parse('2016/12/05 05:18 pm')
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 5, 17, 18)
>>> dt.timestamp()
1480929480.0

>>> parse('16/11/12')
>>> datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 16, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

For use with the `datetime module`, documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)

```
>>>import datetime
>>>a = u'11/5/2003'
>>>time1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, "%m/%d/%Y")
>>>print time1
datetime.datetime(2003, 11, 5, 0, 0)
```

In `ipython`:

```
In [1]: import datetime

In [2]: a = u'11/5/2003'

In [3]: time1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, "%m/%d/%Y")

In [4]: print time1
2003-11-05 00:00:00
```

Use with the `time module`, documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html)

```
>>>import time
>>>a = u'11/5/2003'
>>>time1 = time.strptime(a, "%m/%d/%Y")
>>>print time1
time.struct_time(tm_year=2003, tm_mon=11, tm_mday=5, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=309, tm_isdst=-1)
```

Answer (score 4):

[`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) you use to work with in PHP may be most similar to `dateparser`.

Note if you don't have the `dateparser` library.

Install it with

```
pip3 install dateparser
```

If you are using conda

```
conda install dateparser
```

This library understands over 200 language locales plus numerous formats in a language agnostic fashion.

Parsing generic terms also works:

```
import dateparser
print (dateparser.parse('yesterday')) #2019-05-19 08:08:14.934992
```

And also supports non-Gregorian calendar systems.