# Print the local date and time in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I need to print the real local time in this exact string format: "`20190320130348`". (Year,Month,Day,Hour,Min,Secs).

I found several posts presenting how to print the real local time with the `time` library, but I don't know how to edit it accordingly so I can get this exact format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I strtotime in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546936/how-do-i-strtotime-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`time.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/time.html?highlight=time.strftime#time.strftime):

```
from time import gmtime, strftime
print(strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S", gmtime()))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
20190320111020
```

**EDIT**:

```
print(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime()))  # for readability
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `datetime`:

```
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using `datetime`

```
#import module
import datetime
#get current date and time as a string
now = str(datetime.datetime.now)
#replace what ever you need
now = now.replace("-","").replace(" ","").replace(":","").replace(".","")
```

e.g:

```
now = str(datetime.datetime.now())
print(now)
```

prints out :
`2019-03-20 13:15:56.469000`

after manipulation:

`20190320131556469000`