# How to convert this timestamp 2018-07-11T10:40:09+00:00 to epoch?

Tags: python, timestamp

I am searching nearly 2 days, how to convert this type of timestamp format:
2018-07-11T10:40:09+00:00 gathered from excel cell to an epoch?

The code I use is this:

```
import openpyxl 
import datetime
from datetime import date, datetime, time

path = "/home/UbuntuUser/Desktop/Times.xlsx"
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path) 
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active 
cell_obj = sheet_obj.cell(row = 2, column = 3) 
print(cell_obj.value) 
print(datetime.fromisoformat(cell_obj.value))
print(time.mktime(datetime.fromisoformat(cell_obj.value)))
```

which does not work!
(source: https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-convert-the-current-date-to-an-epoch-timestamp-in-python and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-reading-excel-file-using-openpyxl-module/)

I read this post: [How to convert python timestamp string to epoch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30468371/how-to-convert-python-timestamp-string-to-epoch/30476450)

and I tried to use this code:

```
from datetime import datetime

p = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'
mytime = "2009-03-08T00:27:31.807Z"
epoch = datetime(1970, 1, 1)
print((datetime.strptime(mytime, p) - epoch).total_seconds())
```

but the format of what I read is different, and it does not work... Any idea??

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38035785/397872

Comment: Normally Excel doesn't store a date as a string, it stores it as the number of days from the start of the epoch.  Just multiplying by the number of seconds per day should get what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilizing the [`strftime()` and `strptime()` Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) section from the docs, the following should work:

```
from datetime import datetime

date_time_str_excel = '2018-07-11T10:40:09+00:00'
date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time_str_excel, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
print(date_time_obj)
print(date_time_obj.timestamp())
```

**Output:**

```
2018-07-11 10:40:09+00:00
1531305609.0
```

Comment: you can make use of the built-in `fromisoformat` - [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62769371/10197418).